# Inserting float number in mysql

Tags: mysql, numbers, decimal

hello im trying to insert number copied from another website through crawl method.

For example thats the number im trying to insert:

140.000

so i made a table with the next info:

```
Create table IF NOT EXISTS LJugador(
Fecha date,
vm float(10,6),
nom_jugador varchar(80),
FOREIGN KEY (nom_jugador) REFERENCES Jugadores(nombre),
PRIMARY KEY(Fecha, nom_jugador)
```

where vm is the field where im putting the information. The bigger number im gonna introduce is 20.000.000. The problem is i just can insert the full number with float or decimal putting 6 numbers in the decimal side (which is the maximum of the numbers im gona insert, cus of millions) 
For example if i put 1.230.000 in database is saved as: 1.230000, but when i try to add this amount with another for example 160.000 its give me a result of 161.620000 so i dont know how to do to insert million numbers, i can just add numbers of hundred as 180.000,240.000, etc...

i dont know how to do :S, thanks forward for the help.

Comment: Are you using periods for thousand places and commas for decimal places (I believe European style)?

Comment: Try FLOAT(15,6) or DOUBLE(15,6)

Comment: yeah im using but is because the website where i get the information got this way. how could i add the numbers cus i have tried what float or double (15,6) but still doesnt work :S

Answer (score 0):

Try FLOAT(15,6) or DOUBLE(15,6)